# could not load Twitter source data into Flume

Tags: flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

I am getting the following error while running `import twitter` source data

```
could not find or load main class flume.node.Application error
```

can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for review?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Error: [Could not find or load main class org.apache.flume.node.Application - Install flume on hadoop version 1.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021110/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-flume-node-application-ins) the error your getting similar to that. Its might not be about twitter the error that your getting could be more about how to run flume

After that you can take a look at [Configuring Flume to use Twitter as Source](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2015/12/configuring-flume-to-use-twitter-as.html) for twitter integration